# groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder disable PrettyPrint

Tags: xml, grails, groovy, xml-serialization

I'm using groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder to create XML response but it creates prettyprinted result which is unneeded in production.

```
        def writer = new StringWriter()
        def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
        def cities = cityApiService.list(params)

        xml.methodResponse() {
            resultStatus() {
                result(cities.result)
                resultCode(cities.resultCode)
                errorString(cities.errorString)
                errorStringLoc(cities.errorStringLoc)
            }
}
```

This code produces:

```
<methodResponse> 
  <resultStatus> 
    <result>ok</result> 
    <resultCode>0</resultCode> 
    <errorString></errorString> 
    <errorStringLoc></errorStringLoc> 
  </resultStatus> 
</methodResponse>
```

But i don't need any identation - i just want a plain one-row text :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`IndentPrinter`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/util/IndentPrinter.html#IndentPrinter(java.io.Writer,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean)) can take three parameters: a `PrintWriter`, an indent string, and a boolean `addNewLines`.  You can get the markup you want by setting `addNewLines` to false with an empty indent string, like so:

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

def writer = new StringWriter()
def xml = new MarkupBuilder(new IndentPrinter(new PrintWriter(writer), "", false))

xml.methodResponse() {
    resultStatus() {
        result("result")
        resultCode("resultCode")
        errorString("errorString")
        errorStringLoc("errorStringLoc")
    }
}

println writer.toString()
```

The result:

```
<methodResponse><resultStatus><result>result</result><resultCode>resultCode</resultCode><errorString>errorString</errorString><errorStringLoc>errorStringLoc</errorStringLoc></resultStatus></methodResponse>
```

Comment: `IndentPrinter` takes a `Writer` as its first parameter, not a `PrintWriter`. So you can just pass `writer` directly to it, you don't have construct a `PrintWriter`.

Answer (score 3):

Just looking at the JavaDocs there is a method on [IndentPrinter](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/IndentPrinter.html#setIndentLevel%28int%29) where you can set the Indent level, although it's not going to put it all on a single line for you. Perhaps you can write your own `Printer`

Comment: yep, i saw that - i could disable identation but line breaks are still present.